# Overload division operator in sympy

Tags: python, operator-overloading, sympy, lambdify

I would like to overload the division operator in sympy to handle division by zero.

Here is the context: I have expressions, that are simplified through `sp.simplify`. As a consequence, sympy may simplify an expression into one that makes the division operator `/` appear. Consider for instance those lines of code:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x', real=True)
expr = 5*sp.exp(-1*sp.log(x))
print(expr)
```

Which prints `5/x`. I managed to "override" functions like `log`, for that I just used the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com) and it works:

```
import math

# protected log function for evaluation
def pl(x):
    if x == 0:
        return x
    if x < 0:
        return math.log(-x)
    else:
        return math.log(x)

expr = sp.log(x)
f = sp.lambdify(x, expr, modules={'log': pl})
print(f(2) == f(-2))
```

Which prints `True` as expected. I assume this works because `log` appears in the expression. For `pow`, it is a bit more complicated. I had to use the `ccode` function:

```
# protected pow function
def pp(x, p):
    if not isinstance(p, int) and x < 0:
        return math.pow(-x, p)
    if p < 0 and x == 0:
        return 0
    return math.pow(x, p)

expr = sp.Pow(x, 5.5)
print(expr, sp.ccode(expr))
f = sp.lambdify(x, expr, modules={'pow': pp})
g = sp.lambdify(x, sp.ccode(expr), modules={'pow': pp})
print(g(-2) == g(2), f(-2), g(-2))
```

Which prints `x**5.5 pow(x, 5.5)` and then `True (-1.1087038706409865e-13-45.254833995939045j) 45.254833995939045`. So for `log`, `exp` or `pow` functions, I managed to override at evaluation time. But for the division operator I didn't. `sp.ccode(5/x)` and `5/x` print the same. I would like `5/x` to appear like `div(5, x)` then I could use the `module` keyword argument to override at evaluation time. I understand sympy transforms `/` with a combination of `Mul` and `Pow` functions. But then how to make those operators (`/`, `+`, `-`, `*`) appear like in the `ccode` of `x**5` which gives `pow(x, 5)`?

Comment: `help(f)` should show you the python code that `lambdify` produces. `f.__doc__` might also show that.  Python interpreter translates a `x/y` into `x.__div__(y)`.  So you might be able to overload that method, but I'm not sure of which class.  Same for other operators.  `np.divide` (and other `ufunc`) take a `where` and `out` parameters that let you refine the divide behavior.  That's been covered in other SO.